# Using ENUM in SQLPlus ORA-00907

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

So tried using an ENUM over instructors favoured 'CHECK(col_name IN ('ENUM', 'LIST')) method and got the missing right parentheses error. Could't figure it out and would appreciate any input. My curiousity is academic, the check condition works fine, so no rush.

`SQL> CREATE TABLE service_labour_detail

      2  (call_num NUMBER(8),

      3  labour_code ENUM('A','B','C','D'),

      4  labour_hours NUMBER(3,1) NOT NULL,

      5  PRIMARY KEY(call_num, labour_code),

      6  FOREIGN KEY(call_num)

      7  REFERENCES service_call(call_num));

    labour_code ENUM('A','B','C','D'),

                *
    ERROR at line 3:

    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`


Cheers!

Fraser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum` is not a valid data type in Oracle.  `enum` is a data type in MySQL but, so far as I'm aware, not many other databases support it.

Comment: hmm that's interesting, I am a student so I probably mis-read this [oracle docs link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/enum.html)

Comment: @Fraser - Oracle the company owns MySQL.  So there is a bunch of documentation about MySQL on the oracle.com domain.  That's different than the documentation for Oracle the database.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
QL> SELECT ename
  2  ,      job
  3  ,      CASE deptno
  4            WHEN 10
  5            THEN 'ACCOUNTS'
  6            WHEN 20
  7            THEN 'SALES'
  8            WHEN 30
  9            THEN 'RESEARCH'
 10            WHEN 40
 11            THEN 'OPERATIONS'
 12            ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
 13         END AS department
 14  FROM   emp;

from this link http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=206